# How to stop a Cypress test but mark it as a success?

Tags: cypress

I have a Cypress test that clicks a link which runs a method and then brings the user to a new page on different website entirely.

This is the test:

```javascript
it('Cards', () => {
    cy.get('#my-id').click({ force: true })
    var itemID= localStorage.getItem('itemID')
    expect(itemID).to.eq(null);
    cy.get(`a:visible[id*="the_link"]`).first().click()
    Cypress.on('fail', (error, runnable) => {
        var itemID= localStorage.getItem('itemID')
        expect(itemID).to.not.equal(null)
        // end test but mark as a success
    })
})
```

The problem is that I get a cross origin error, therefore I added in the `Cypress.on('fail')` piece of code. So now, the test does not fail but it waits for minutes because it attempting to intercept more data. There is a lot of other stuff going on so I cannot change the intercept logic.

All I want is to end the test and mark it a success on the line that says `// end test but mark as a success`.

Is this possible?

Comment: Can you post the HTML of the link that redirects the user?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Chrome-based browsers you might wanna try [setting `chromeWebSecurity` to `false`](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/web-security#Set-chromeWebSecurity-to-false).

Other browsers (specifically Firefox) might still run into that issue, to which you might wanna properly address the on failure method or split the interaction with another origin to another `it` statement. The later is pretty simple and should work on all browsers:

```javascript
it('Cards', () => {
    cy.get('#my-id').click({ force: true })
}) //if that gets you to another superdomain, we go to another it
it('Another superdomain', () => {
    var itemID= localStorage.getItem('itemID')
    expect(itemID).to.eq(null);
    cy.get(`a:visible[id*="the_link"]`).first().click()
}) If that is yet another superdomain, we go to another it again
it('Third superdomain', () => {
    var itemID= localStorage.getItem('itemID')
    expect(itemID).to.not.equal(null)
    // test ends by itself
})
```

The way you describe on failure method, you just provide additional functionality for the failure but do not instruct the method to ignore the test status finalisation.

That can be done by returning false on that specific event:

```javascript
Cypress.on('fail', () => false);
```

Mind that you can probably include an assertion before returning false if it is really required.

```javascript
Cypress.on('fail', () => { // no params are needed tho
  var itemID= localStorage.getItem('itemID')
  expect(itemID).to.not.equal(null)
  // end test but mark as a success
  return false
})
```

That piece of code must be provided right before the potential failure event. This will interrupt the test as it will fail but will mark it as passed.

This is a huge anti-pattern and generalisation, as you use a `Cypress.on('fail', ())` event. Better way is to anchor any sort of negative logic to a more specific event, one of those listed [here](https://docs.cypress.io/api/events/catalog-of-events). However, that specific hack above might work for avoiding cross origin error on non-chrome-based browsers if it is for sure the last thing that happens in that test.

Comment: I tried this and it made it the last `expect` but in the cypress log, you could see the test was still waiting on `fetch` of some api so it runs forever.

Comment: Are you using Cypress with UI? Can you see the test timer still going as well? Does launching this test in a batch with other test make it impossible for other tests to start?